# Technique for adding flourishes to div corners and borders: CSS3 Multiple Backgrounds or Border Images?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm 'embellishing' an existing website with some nice flourishes to the corners and borders of a content `div`.  Without changing the markup at all (as it is generated by a CMS), how can I add 'flourish' images (ie [corner flourishes like this](http://www.flickr.com/photos/29685293@N07/2783079594/)) and fancy borders using CSS only?

Fancy ASCII Art representation of what I want to achieve (outer border represents div):

```
---------------------------------------------
|                                           |
|  #%%%      ....................      %%%# |
|  %                                      % |
|  %                                      % |
|                                           |
| .                                       . |
| .                                       . |
| .                                       . |
| .                                       . |
| .                                       . |
| .                                       . |
| .                                       . |
| .                                       . |
| .                                       . |
| .                                       . |
| .                                       . |
|                                           |
| %                                       % |
| %                                       % |
| #%%%      ....................       %%%# |
---------------------------------------------
```

The div can expand vertically.  It needs to work across browsers (CSS3PIE is being used).  And the div already has a background image.

Is [CSS3 Multiple Backgrounds](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#layering) the way to go?  Or are [CSS3 Border Images](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-images) the best way?

Which technique will give the best flexibility in terms of the handling the vertically expanding div as well as how far inset the borders / corners can be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax should be something like this:

```
.flourish{
width: 500px; /* just an example */
height: auto;
background-image: url(decoration1.png), url(decoration2.png), url(decoration3.png), url(decoration4.png), url(background.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left top, right top, right bottom, left bottom, left top;
}
```

Kind of nasty having all those images to load...
If the width is fixed then you could just have a top and bottom ornament background.

It would be even better if you could use the same image and just rotate it using css, but I am not aware of any background property to handle that.

Comment: I looked a little more at border image, but that does some stretching along the sides and may work better with a more symmetrical design.